# Habria una manera de poner un condicional if dentro de un IMPORT de excel laravel? para que no se pongan el rol admin?

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Me gustaria poner una condicion de que si el *rol* que se puso es un *rol* **admin** que tire error. Alguien sabrá la mejor forma de hacer esto dentro del `cmusuarioimport` que pongo a continuacion:

Como un **required** en donde si el usuario pone un *rol* que no corresponde lo ponga como error y que lo diga por *consola*.

```
 {

       // use RemembersRowNumber;gi
       use Importable, SkipsFailures;
    
       private $numRows;
       private $nombre = [
           "name",
           "email",
           "legajo",
           "empresa",
           "telefono",
           "nro_documento",
       ];
    
       public function __construct($array){
           $this ->  nombre['name'] = $array[0];
           $this ->  nombre['last_name'] = $array[1];
           $this ->  nombre['rol'] = $array[2];
           $this ->  nombre['nro_documento'] = $array[3];
       }
       public function model(array $row)
       {
            $empresa = Empresa::where('nombre_fantasia','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['empresa']])->get();
            $sucursal = Sucursal::where('nombre','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['sucursal']])->get();
            $gerencia = Gerencia::where('nombre','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['gerencia']])->get();
            $nombre_rol = Role::where('name','=', $row[ $this ->  nombre['rol']])->get();
    
    
              $nro_documento = $row[ $this ->  nombre['nro_documento']];
             $last_name = $row[ $this ->  nombre['last_name']];
             $rest = substr( $nro_documento, -4);
             $password = $last_name . $rest;
    
    
           ++$this->numRows;
           $usuario= User::updateOrCreate([
               'name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['name']],
               'last_name' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['last_name']],
               'email' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['email']],
               'password' => Hash::make($password),
               'nro_documento' => $row[ $this ->  nombre['nro_documento']],    
            ]);
            $role = RoleUser::updateOrCreate([
                'role_id' => $nombre_rol != '[]' ? $nombre_rol[0] -> id : null,
                'user_id' => $usuario->id,
             ]);
    
       }
    
       public function rules(): array
       {
           return [
    
                    $this ->  nombre['name'] => 'required|max:20',
                    $this ->  nombre['last_name'] => 'required|max:20',
                    $this ->  nombre['email']    => 'required|max:50|unique:users,email',
                    $this ->  nombre['empresa'   ]=> 'required|max:20',
                    $this ->  nombre['tipo_documento'   ]=> 'required|max:5',
                    $this ->  nombre['nro_documento'   ]=> 'required|max:20|unique:users,nro_documento',    
       }
    
       public function batchSize(): int
       {
           return 600;
       }
       public function chunkSize(): int
       {
           return 1000;
       }
```

En **rol** debería dejar elegir el *rol* que quieran, **menos el rol adminitrador**, de esta manera no darle un permiso especial. No encuentro la mejor forma de aplicarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a poner esto al principio de la función `model`:

```php
public function model(array $row)
   {
       if ($this->nombre['rol'] == "admin") {
           die("Error: No se permite asignar este usuario admin de este modo.");
       }
(y a continuación el resto de código que ya existe)
```

La verdad no se si el rol se llama `admin`, o `administrador`, pero esa es la idea.

Con eso verificas el valor de `$this->nombre['rol']`, y si es coincidente con `admin` muestras un error y paras la función.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta muy util